# Bash file for docker invalid reference $PWD

Tags: bash, docker

I wrote a bash file to automatically build a docker image and run the docker. The build goes fine however i get an invalid reference error for using $PWD. The command is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
app="docker.test2"
docker build -t ${app} .
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 -v $PWD:/usr/src/Deployment -w /usr/src/Deployment/microblog2 ${app} flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

When I replace the $PWD with the actual file path it works fine. I also tried replacing it with $pwd, $(pwd) and ${pwd} but to no avail. The error is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Docker never *sees* the `$PWD`; it has no way to know that that shell syntax was used, as you can verify if you run `bash -x yourscript` to enable trace logging during the script's execution. With that logging enabled, you'll see that the `$PWD` reference is replaced with the actual directory name before docker is even started.

Comment: ...but really, **do** run `bash -x yourscript`, and compare that to the trace logs generated when running `set -x` at an interactive prompt, and then running the same (working!) command there. If there's something like a hidden character in your script, or any other difference between how the command is executed in the two environments, that'll expose it.

Comment: Keep an eye out, in particular, for the last argument becoming `$'0.0.0.0\r'` in the trace logs; if you see that, it means your script was saved as a DOS/Windows text file, instead of in UNIX format.

Comment: One other thing: If your directory name contains spaces, you'll need double quotes around the `$PWD`. That is, `"$PWD":/usr/src/Deployment`, or `"$PWD:/usr/src/Deployment"`. That said, any bugs caused by a lack of quotes will show up in the `set -x` logs, so consider the request for them reiterated again. :)

Comment: Can you post the command that you run with the actual file path?

Comment: Sorry, what's the actual error message you're getting?  Can you replace the image you've attached here with the actual text of that error?

Comment: the error no longer appears now, i changed the $PWD to $(pwd). however this still does not explain what happened. unfortunately i could not recreate the error and thus had nothing useful to look at from bash -x myscript

Comment: @DavidMaze the second to last line in the screenshot is the actual error. docker: invalid reference format

Comment: @NguyenLamPhuc the command i run is simply bash start.sh with the $PWD replaced with my actual file path,  the path that $PWD should have given me automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
Docker/test:latest
```

should work fine

Comment: dont understand this, could you please supplement this answer?